# Rendering formatted phone number with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am writing a pipe in Angular that renders the appropriate formatted phone number depending on what is contained in the string.

Input: string
possible cases that need to be rendered: 
+1 (123) 456-7891 (country code + tendigit)
(123) 456-7891 (ten digit)
(123) 456-7891 ext1234 (tendigit with extension)
+ 1 (123) 456-7891 ext1234 (country code, tendigit, extension)

My current code:

```
const rawPhoneNumber = '1(626) 423-3343 ex123'
const pattern = /(\d{1})?([a-zA-Z\d]{3})([a-zA-Z\d]{3})([a-zA-Z\d]{4})(.*)/
const matches = rawPhoneNumber.replace(/[\W_]*/g, '').match(pattern);
let arrOfDigits = matches.filter((item, index) => item != undefined);
arrOfDigits = arrOfDigits.filter((item, index) => item.length)

// simple Phone
if (arrOfDigits.length === 4) {
  console.log(`(${arrOfDigits[1]}) ${arrOfDigits[2]}-${arrOfDigits[3]}`)  
}
// prephonesuffix
if (arrOfDigits.length === 6) {
  console.log(`+${arrOfDigits[1]} (${arrOfDigits[2]}) ${arrOfDigits[3]}-${arrOfDigits[4]} ${arrOfDigits[5]}`)
}
// pre or suff
if (arrOfDigits.length === 5) { 
  if (arrOfDigits[1].length <= 2) {
    console.log(`${arrOfDigits[1]} (${arrOfDigits[2]}) ${arrOfDigits[3]}-${arrOfDigits[4]}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`(${arrOfDigits[1]}) ${arrOfDigits[2]}-${arrOfDigits[3]} ${arrOfDigits[4]}`)
  }
}
```

My issue is, this is very easy to break if the number is not perfect. I would like any suggestions as to how I could cover more cases.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js#readme

Answer (score 2):

I've created a directive for this purpose.

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/saideldah/bf0b7259b8b647a10dce852df32bb278)